# How to install NLog for client applications

Tags: installation, client, inno-setup, nlog

I'm trying to find some documentation on how to install NLog for a client application.  Everything works find in development environment (Visual Studio 2019) when I add Nlog using, but I am not sure what to so that end users can run my application on their desktops/laptops, etc. without having to install Nlog themselves.

I'm using Innosetup to create my installer.

BTW, the "application" in question is an astronomy camera driver, using a standard called ASCOM.  It's effectively a COM object.

Any pointers or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Tom

Comment: Please remove this question.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it was a silly question.  Putting nlog.dll in the same directory as the application seems to be working.